# Displaying the website's content (html) through the specific browser - is it possible to realize?

Tags: html, cross-browser, browser

I'm interested is there a possibility that could allow to display website's content or to say exactly an HTML through a specific browser installed on the web server?

I mean something like a module for a web server may be, that can display the website's content through the built-in browser, ignoring the clients browser?

If this possibility really exists, so I don't need to adopt my HTML to different browsers.

Comment: Weren't Flash and Java Applets type of technologies created to achieve something like this? Like to by pass the rendering of client browser? But sadly, they also require some kind of client side installation.

I think the browsers today restrict this behavior because that would be a security problem?

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't any web server module that takes control over the client's computer.

Depending on your situation I suppose you could replace the HTML page with Flash, Silverlight or a Java applet if that would make things easier.

Comment: +1. Having to adapt HTML and CSS is, unfortunately, still part of a web developer's tasks. If you want pixel perfect rendering on all browsers, then Flash or similar technologies are a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make some pdfs or images if you really want a specific rendering, but it's really not a website anymore at that point.  You could also beg your users to use a particular browser, but they'll probably ignore you.  The world spends (wastes) gazillions of dollars on good, standards-compliant HTML and CSS for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

How about a browser in a Java applet?